what could be a possible reason why i'm not getting the full response in my flutter app as i am getting in postman
so I am suposed to make an API call to fetch data plans from an endpoint url, it returns the complete data in postman which is
{
    "status": true,
    "data_plans": [
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "MTN CG 500MB",
            "planid": 7,
            "gig_measurment": 0,
            "plan_code": 106,
            "validity": "30 Days",
            "network": 1,
            "plan_type": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "name": "MTN CG 1GB",
            "planid": 8,
            "gig_measurment": 1,
            "plan_code": 107,
            "validity": "30 Days",
            "network": 1,
            "plan_type": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "name": "MTN CG 2GB",
            "planid": 9,
            "gig_measurment": 2,
            "plan_code": 108,
            "validity": "30 Days",
            "network": 1,
            "plan_type": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 15,
            "name": "MTN CG 3GB",
            "planid": 10,
            "gig_measurment": 3,
            "plan_code": 109,
            "validity": "30 Days",
            "network": 1,
            "plan_type": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "name": "MTN CG 5GB",
            "planid": 11,
            "gig_measurment": 5,
            "plan_code": 110,
            "validity": "30 Days",
            "network": 1,
            "plan_type": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 17,
            "name": "MTN CG 10GB",
            "planid": 12,
            "gig_measurment": 10,
            "plan_code": 111,
            "validity": "30 Days",
            "network": 1,
            "plan_type": 2
        }
    ]
}

instead this is what i get as response in my flutter app
Response data: {status: true, data_plans: []}

Future<void> fetchDataPlans() async {
  final url = 'https://yourapi.com/getdataplans/';
  final requestPayload = {
    'network': selectedNetwork.toString(),
    'selectedPlanType': '2',
  };

  debugPrint('Fetching data plans with payload: $requestPayload');

  try {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(requestPayload),
    );

    debugPrint('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
    debugPrint('Response body: ${response.body}');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final dynamic responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      debugPrint('Response data: $responseData');

      List<Map<String, dynamic>> plans;
      if (responseData is Map && responseData['status'] == true && responseData['data_plans'] is List) {
        plans = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(responseData['data_plans']);
      } else {
        throw Exception('Unexpected response format');
      }

      debugPrint('Parsed data plans: $plans');

      setState(() {
        dataPlans = plans;
        selectedDataPlan = plans.isNotEmpty ? plans.first['plan_code'].toString() : '';
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data plans');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint('Error fetching data plans: $e');
  }
}


code looks perfect, once check selectedPlanType id which you are putting in postman and in your api calling request payload
